# HTML Margin Issue - Body Is Scrollable Past Declared Width

Tags: html, css

So I've got the body set at 100% width, but there's a 10px-or-so surplus on the right. I've got quite a lot of code, so instead of paste it all here, I'll just give the jsFiddle which has all my HTML, CSS and JS. I've been tinkering around with this for HOURS and I can't figure it out.

Here's the CSS I'd HOPED would clear up these kinds of issues:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
} 
body {
background: url(http://www.moblah.com/pics/ricepaper.png);
background-attachment: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
}
```

Here's the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/fHGNT/

I'm a beginner, so be kind :)

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what you are trying to accomplish.  Are you trying to prevent the page from having the horizontal scroll bar?

Comment: @RacerNerd: Precisely. I've tried `overflow-x:hidden` which did nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there you go: `div.close{ right:-20px; }`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm PRETTY sure it's not any of the off-screen `div`s. `div.close` is positioned absolutely inside `div.choose`. I tried getting rid of that anyway, to no avail.

Comment: @MyCompassSpins You are wrong:P `<div class="close"><a href="#">X</a></div><div id="mail" class="hiddenSocial">`. Remove first `div.close` to check. You need to replace that negative right position for it

Comment: You're right, sorry! I was commenting out the CSS and ignoring the HTML. Is there a way to position those outside the margin of `div.choose` without offsetting anything else?

Comment: @n1kkou: Turns out I had an EXTRA `div.close`, and that's what was offsetting the page. I got rid of that and everything's positioned just right without hiding the overflow. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: @MyCompassSpins You're welcome, i was lost in your html code right now, tried to get an idea of what you wanted to do there. You need more layout order(indentation and spacing) in your future projects :P

Comment: @n1kou: Haha, agreed. I've pretty much spent all my time on the JavaScript, so the cleanliness of the HTML has been ignored. That'll get fixed before the page goes live.

Answer (score 1):

This fixes your problem.

```
body {
   overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/fHGNT/1/

I was searching for what is causing the overflow-x in the first place. And the thing I suspect is doing it is the bottom right social media sliders.

Comment: this will fix the issue, it's caused by the #hidden div

Comment: @AlienArrays: I had tried that and, oddly, it works in the fiddle, but has no effect when I test the page locally from my computer. Is this something that will only work properly when the page is online?

Comment: Also, someone above discovered that it was the `margin-right:-20px` on `div.close` which is the culprit.

Comment: @AlienArrays: Did you change/edit anything besides the `overflow`? I can't get it to work for me outside the fiddle. Perplexing.

Comment: @AlienArrays: Hmm . . . well, the only difference between the fiddle and my local code is everything that comes before the `<body>` tag. Any idea if it's possible for a `<meta>`, `<link>` or `<script>` to interfere with the css?

Comment: @AlienArrays: I had a redundant `div.close`, and getting rid of that solves the problem. I definitely appreciate the attention and feedback, though!